# Android dialog wrap_content not working

Tags: java, android

I have a **custom dialog** set up and I have the layout's width set to `wrap_content` but it is still taking the entire screen width. I even tried setting the width to **100dp** and it still uses the whole screen Why does this happen?

> I have set up the dialog like this:

```
public class DialogGoToLine extends Dialog
{
//The root view of the dialog
private static View rootView;

public DialogGoToLine(Context context, int themeResId){
    super(context, themeResId);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Allow the dialog to be canceled by tapping out of its bounds
    setCancelable(true);

    //Inflate the custom layout
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(HotspotHelper.getAppContext());
    rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_go_to_line, null);

    //Set up the layout
    //setTitle(HotspotHelper.getAppContext().getString(R.string.clientDetails));
    //setTitle("Go to line");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(rootView);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextGoToLine);

    Button buttonGoToLine = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonGoToLine);
    buttonGoToLine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View p1)
            {
                int line = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()) - 1;
                ((LinearLayoutManager)LogActivity.recyclerViewLog.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(line, (int)HotspotHelper.dpToPx(30));
                dismiss();
            }
    });
}
}
```

> And the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewGoToLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:labelFor="@+id/editTextGoToLine"
    android:text="Go to line: "
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:textColor="@color/primaryText"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@id/editTextGoToLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGoToLine"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Edit 1**
If it makes a difference, this dialog has a style in which I declared the background to this drawable:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>`

Comment: Long shot: I've faced dialog related bugs in Studio's Instant Run. If you are using it, can you try uninstalling the app and retrying?

Comment: Your parent linear_layout width is 100dp

Comment: @Shaishav I am currently using AIDE on my phone which does not have instant run

Comment: @vinoth12594 I tried it with 100dp but the problem is it still takes up the entire screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, removing the theme that I applied to the dialog fixed the wrap_content issue. The only thing the custom theme did was set the background of the dialog, but removing it has solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use have to use this method  `setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)` instead of `setContentView(rootView);`

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params= new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//ViewGroup.LayoutParams params= new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
//        300,
//       300);
//for coustom size
params.height = thumb_size;
params.width = thumb_size;
// set padding ,margins ,gravity as your desired
```

Use this **setContentView(rootView, params);**

Comment: getLayoutParams() is giving me a NPE

Comment: Create new layout parameters with your desired width and height it's sample code for layout parameters.

Comment: I have already resolved this issue by removing the background attribute from the custom theme and just applying it to the parent layout instead of the dialog itself

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue, and i came across a solution. If you give fixed width or wrap_content to your root of your layout, it doesn't consider that. I don't know the reason behind this. Put one more parent layout inside your root and give required width and height to the inner parent, put all views inside this parent. I hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        //put all your views inside this linear layout

        <TextView......./>
        <TextView......./>
        <TextView......./>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, the dialog still has a bunch of empty space on the right side of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Try this before showing the dialog:

```
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_width), WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```

`dialog_width` is `100dp`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `android:orientation="vertical"` in your main Linear Layout because You are using linear layout with horizontal orientation so all the widgets are aligned horizontally and they are acquiring their assigned space horizontally that's why it cover the whole screen.